# An undesired consequence of \vbox{}

Tags: page-breaking

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blah hlah
\vbox{
\item blah blah
}
item blah blah
```

I did this to prevent page breaks within one item.

But now the numbers of all the items after the \vbox{} are indented rather than vertically aligned with the numbers of the foregoing items.

I tried again like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blah hlah
\item
\vbox{
blah blah
}
item blah blah
```

Same thing.

How can I change that?

Comment: Why not `\nopagebreak`? In any case, please post a complete, compilable example people can use to reproduce the issue. That is much more helpful than mere fragments of code.

Comment: @cfr : I don't see how that can work. [This](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_110.html) web page says "The \nopagebreak command prevents LaTeX from breaking the current page at the point of the command."  But my purpose was to prevent it from putting a page break between two specified points, not just at one specified point.

Comment: That is why it is so important to post a Minimal Working Example which demonstrates the issue. Otherwise, all anybody can do is guess. (But egreg's guesses tend to be pretty good! Have you tried his solution?)

Answer (score 9):

Never use undocumented commands without knowing what they do. In particular, `\vbox` is a primitive command that misses several adjustments `minipage` or `\parbox` do in order to be as compatible as possible with the surrounding context.

Also the reference point of `\vbox` is on the bottom line inside it.

Here's a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{nbitem}
 {\par\vspace{\parsep}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}}
 {\par\xdef\nbitemprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}%
  \end{minipage}\par\prevdepth=\nbitemprevdepth}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item blah blah

\begin{nbitem}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{nbitem}

\item blah blah

\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]